# Plot the gene FPKM normalized counts value with ggplot2 in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, mean

I just want to plot a image with the x named different samples and y named different gene symbols. Also I want to add geom_errorbar using ggplot2 in shiny.

I hope if I input a gene symbol, the plot will appear beside.

But I tried times but I don't know why it didn't show.

There are two input files.One is the mean value of each samples and the other one is the sd value file.

my code sample like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

mean_data<-data.frame(Name=c(paste0("Group_",LETTERS[1:20])),
                      matx<-matrix(sample(1:1000,1000,replace = T),nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1]<-c(paste0("Gene_",1:50))
sd_data<-data.frame(Name=c(paste0("Group_",LETTERS[1:20])),
                    matx<-matrix(runif(1000,5,10),nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1]<-c(paste0("Gene_",1:50))



# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h4("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot"),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(
      
      textInput(inputId = "GeneSymbol",
                label = "Input your Gene Symbol:",
                value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = 'e.g. Igfbp7,Zzz3'
      ),
      actionButton("button", "show")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput(outputId = "barplot")
      
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  gene <- reactive({
    gene<-input$GeneSymbol
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    cat("Showing", input$GeneSymbol)
  })
  p <- reactive({ggplot(data=mean_data,aes_string(x=mean_data$Name,y=mean_data$input$GeneSymbol,fill=randomColor(74)))+
      geom_bar(stat='identity',position=position_dodge(0.5),width=0.9)+
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean_data$input$GeneSymbol-totalsd$input$GeneSymbol, ymax = mean_data$input$GeneSymbol+totalsd$input$GeneSymbol),width=.2)+
      theme_classic2()+
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45)+
      theme(legend.position = "none")+
      labs(title=input$GeneSymbol,x=NULL,y="FPKM_value")+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20,1,1,1), "mm"))
  })
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({    
    print(p())
    
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I know there are many wrong codes.
I'm new in shiny.
Please help this child.
Many thanks！！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bugs in code. However in my opinion your code could be simplified and the bugs avoided by reshaping your data in the beginning:

1. Bind your mean and sd in one data frame using e.g. `dplyr::bind_rows`
2. Reshape your dataset using `tidyr::pivot_longer/wider`.

After doing so we end up with a data frame with four columns, i.e. `Name` (Sample?), `Gene`, `mean` and `sd`.

This alone simplifies the plotting code and avoids all the bugs as you could refer to fixed column names.

3. To show only selected genes I added a reactive `plot_data` to filter the data accordingly.
4. Besides a text input I added a `selectInput` to select the desired genes

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mean_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(sample(1:1000, 1000, replace = T), nrow = 20)
)
names(mean_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

sd_data <- data.frame(
  Name = c(paste0("Group_", LETTERS[1:20])),
  matx <- matrix(runif(1000, 5, 10), nrow = 20)
)
names(sd_data)[-1] <- c(paste0("Gene_", 1:50))

# Prepare dataset.
#   1. Bind mean and sd data
#   2. Reshape
data <- dplyr::bind_rows(list(
  mean = mean_data,
  sd = sd_data
), .id = "stat")
data_long <- data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-c(Name, stat), names_to = "Gene", values_to = "value") %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "stat", values_from = "value")

# Define UI for app that draws a histogram ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("Gene_FPKM Value Barplot"),
  br(),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput(
        inputId = "GeneSymbol",
        label = "Input your Gene Symbol:",
        value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "e.g. Igfbp7,Zzz3"
      ),
      selectInput(
        "slctGeneSymbol", 
        "Select Gene Symbols:", 
        choices = unique(data_long$Gene),
        multiple = TRUE
      )
      #actionButton("button", "show")
    ),

    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(outputId = "barplot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    cat("Showing", input$GeneSymbol)
  })

  plot_data <- reactive({
    subset(data_long, Gene %in% input$slctGeneSymbol)
  })
  
  output$barplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = plot_data(), aes(x = Name, y = mean, fill = Gene)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(0.9), width = 0.9) +
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), width = .2, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
      theme_classic2() +
      rotate_x_text(angle = 45) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      labs(title = input$GeneSymbol, x = NULL, y = "FPKM_value") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
      theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20, 1, 1, 1), "mm"))
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can do it now. But what want to do more is how can I  add the “fill”parameter  of ggplot2  equals to the length of Name . I tried but sth wrong with it.Plz.